# Python: Calculate sum of numbers of the corresponding positions in different csv files

Tags: python, csv

I have 1000 csv files with the same shape (for example 100*100). All cells are filled with only numbers. I want each cell in the result file to be the sum of the corresponding position numbers of other 1000 files.

Example: three 3*3 csv files

```
|0 0 0|   |1 1 1|   |0 1 2|
|0 1 2|   |0 0 0|   |0 0 0|
|1 1 1|   |1 1 1|   |1 1 1|
```

The result file should give:

```
|1 3 3|
|0 1 2|
|3 3 3|
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you trying to do this using only the python standard library?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several ways to do this, but I would recommend using the [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library. This library provides many useful methods for working with spreadsheets.

```
import pandas as pd

filenames = ["0.csv", "1.csv", "2.csv"]
df = sum((pd.read_csv(filename) for filename in filenames))
df.to_csv("result.csv", index=False, header=False)
```

Here is an explanation of what is happening in `sum((pd.read_csv(filename) for filename in filenames))`. That line iterates over each item in your list of filenames, and it loads each file as a Pandas DataFrame (`pd.DataFrame`). You can add `pd.DataFrame` objects together, and we do it here using the builtin function `sum`. This is also efficient, because it does not load all of the files into memory. It loads the files in a lazy fashion.

You can also use the [Numpy](https://numpy.org/) library, a very popular library for numerical processing.

```
import numpy as np
filenames = ["0.csv", "1.csv", "2.csv"]
result = sum((np.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter=",") for filename in filenames))
np.savetxt("result.csv", result, delimiter=",")
```

This solution is faster than the solution using Pandas.

Comment: you may need to use glob to read filenames automatically `filenames = glob.glob("/home/adam/*.csv")`

Answer (score 0):

This code validates the size of array before populating the sum

```py
 
 #!/usr/bin/env python3

 from csv import reader
 from glob import glob


 def column_row(fd):
    cl = None
    for e,r in enumerate(fd):
       if cl == None:
           cl = len(r)
       else: 
           continue
    return cl, (e+1)

 csv_list = glob('./*csv')
 f = reader(open(csv_list[0]))
 cl, rl = column_row(f)
 s_matrix = [[0]*cl for r in range(rl)]
 for filename in csv_list:
    fd = reader(open(filename))
    for er,r in enumerate(fd):
        for ec, c in enumerate(r):
            s_matrix[er][ec] += int(c)
 print(s_matrix)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using only the standard library.  It will not be particularly efficient compared to the use of numpy or similar, but to sum the values from 1000 files with 100x100 takes only a few seconds (timed at under 4 seconds on hardware from 2013), so optimisation may be lower priority than the benefits of using standard packages.

```
import csv
import glob

inputs = glob.glob("input*.csv")  # adjust as required
output = 'total.csv'

totals = []

first_file = True
for fname in inputs:
    with open(fname) as f:
        c = csv.reader(f)
        for i, row in enumerate(c):
            values = [int(cell) for cell in row]
            if first_file:
                totals.append(values)
            else:
                trow = totals[i]
                for j in range(len(values)):
                    trow[j] += values[j]
    first_file = False

with open(output, "w") as f:
    c = csv.writer(f)
    c.writerows(totals)
```